# How to select the fields in the mongoose document when I have already found it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I do find the document with fields _id, i do manipulating uses _id and i want return document to the client already without _id. How do it?

The only way i found:

```
sources = {
    VK_Accounts: sources.VK_Accounts.map(vk_account => {
        vk_account._id = null;
        vk_account.settings.Account = null;
        vk_account.settings.access_token = null;
        vk_account.settings._id = null;
        vk_account.Sources.map(vk_source => {
            vk_source._id = null;
            vk_source.settings.Account = null;
            vk_source.settings.access_token = null;
            vk_source.settings._id = null;
            return vk_source;
        })
        return vk_account;
    })
}
```

Possibly i have other more normal way?

Comment: Well there are other ways of course. Is this output from a query using `populate()` or is it embedded data in the document from a single collection? Showing the schema for anything involved and the actual query issued would help your question greatly.

Comment: Juste put `{_id: 0}` in the projection part of your query, it will return documents without the _id field. Or you can use `delete` javascript's operator on your object

Comment: I know that I can add ['-_id'] and this field will disappear, the problem is that I need this field, and when I give the result to the client it is already don't need necessary.
Okay, I'll leave it as it is. I have not been able to find another way for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delete operator in your mongoose model.
For example:

```
Schema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj._id;
  return obj;
};
```

This will remove _id from your output. Hope this works.